# Find the value of $dy/dx$ at $x=8$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Given that variables $xy=40$, find $dy/dx$ at $x=8$.

I used $40/8$ to get $y=5$.
So why is the answer $-5/8$ and not $5/8$?

Comment: You should find derivative of $y$ wr.t. $x$, not $y$ itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$xy=40\Rightarrow8y=40\Rightarrow y=5$
$xy=40\Rrightarrow xdy+ydx=0\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}=-\frac{5}{8}$

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting your equation you get:

$$y=\frac{40}{x}$$

Differentiating:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{40}{x})=\frac{d}{dx}(40x^{-1})=-40x^{-2}=-\frac{40}{x^2}$$

Pluggin in $x=8$

$$\implies -\frac{40}{64}=-\frac{5}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$xy=40\implies y(x) = \frac{40}x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{40}{x^2},\ x = 8 \implies \dots$$

Comment: Why $xy = 40 \implies y = \frac{80}{x}$?

Comment: I made a bunch of silly typos, thank you @6005 for the fix

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$xy=40 \implies y = \frac{40}{x}. $$
Remember that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}  = - \frac{1}{x^2}$$
so
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{40}{x} = 40\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x} =- \frac{40}{x^2}.   $$

Therefore we have, when $x = 8$, that
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{40}{8^2} = -\frac{40}{64} = -\frac58. $$